# Why is the CakePHP password field is empty when trying to access it using $this->data?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I am implementing an authentication component,
This is my registration page

```
create('User',array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $form->input('primary_email',array('size'=> 32));
    echo $form->input('password',array('label' => 'Password'));
    echo $form->input('remember_me',array('label' => 'Remember Me','type'=>'checkbox','checked' => 'false'));
    echo $html->link('Forgot Password','/users/forgot/');
    echo $form->end('Login'); 

    // Javascripts
    echo $javascript->link('jquery',false);
    //echo $javascript->link('jquery.validate.js',false);
    //echo $javascript->codeBlock($code, array('inline' => false)); 

?>
```

When I print the contents of $this->data the password field turns up empty. 
How can I resolve this?

When I rename password to password2 or something else it works !!! Strange

Answer (score 2):

this is because the Auth component removes the password from the data array (for security purposes). why would you want it to contain the password anyway?  the remember me logic (which I assume you are using from the form fields) will handle logging someone in without the password.

Comment: yes but initially if i want to use $this->Auth->login($this->data) it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and mrlanrat's suggestion worked for me.

Instead of trying to access $this->data['password'], you will need to access $this->Auth->data['password']

What basically happens is that the Auth component hashes the password and moves the hashed version into $this->Auth->data. The non-hashed version is deleted for security purposes.

So whenever you need to deal with data related to Auth component, make sure you're using $this->Auth->data and not $this->data.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see your login() function as well but indeed this problem seems weird. You can work around this by renaming your password field and then inside your login function do something like:

```
$this->data['password']=$this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['pwd']);
//now you can call $this->Auth->login and it will work
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may be able to do is have the user confirm their password, and use it for the login function.  I may be completely mis-reading what you're trying to accomplish, but if you have the user Confirm their password w/ a password 2 field, you can compare the two, and also use the starting state of the confirmation password for whatever it is that you're wanting to do.
So:

```
echo $form->input('password', array('label' => 'password'));
echo $form->input('password2', array('label' => 'Confirm Password'));
```

Inside of your logic for whatever you're wanting to accomplish, you can just put:

```
$morePermanentDataStorage = $this->data['User']['password2'];
if($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['password2']) {
//function logic here
}
```

I am also assuming that your form logic from above actually starts with:

```
echo $form->create('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some ExtJS authentication I was working on some weeks back.

A weird workaround is to go to `/config/core.php` and change the debug level temporarily e.g. change from `Configure::write('debug', 0);` to `Configure::write('debug', 1);` and then run your code - not necessarily the part with the Auth component - (and afterwards change the debug level back if you wish). `$this->data['User']['password']` will now be populated with the hash value as intended.

What causes this in the first place still beats me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Using $this->Auth->data['User']['user'] and $this->Auth->data['User']['password'] fixed it.

It looks like the auth controller removed the password from the data when it does its automagic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was related to using the email field for login thru this method

`$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');`

I couldn't resolve it, so I opted to include a username field on my database and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to comment the code `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);` in the file `core.php`

Comment: you really want to reanimate a 3 year old post (even if @Shiv sadly didnt select an answer yet)?^^ especially since your answer doesnt seem to relate to the topic.