# How can I save an automatically generated password in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, registration, authentication

I am trying to automatically register users. You enter an email address and it sends the user a password. Sounds simple enough, right? Here are a bunch of things that I've tried in my add action, but none of them work (as indicated).

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->User->create();

    $random_pass = $this->Auth->password($this->generatePassword());

    // Doesn't work:
    $user_data['User'] = $this->data['User'];
    $user_data['User']['password'] = $random_pass;
    if ($this->User->save($user_data)) { /* ... */ }

    // Doesn't work:
    $this->User->set('password', $random_pass);
    if ($this->User->save($this->data)) { /* ... */ }

    // Doesn't work:
    $this->data['User']['password'] = $random_pass;
    if ($this->User->save($this->data)) { /* ... */ }

    // Doesn't work:
    $this->data['User'][0]['password'] = $random_pass; 
    if ($this->User->saveAll($this->data)) { /* ... */ }

}
```

According to [Why is the CakePHP password field is empty when trying to access it using $this->data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960415/cakephp-password-field-is-empty) it's because the Auth component is removing the password. Seems common enough, no? So how do I get around it?

**More information**

I'm using [this function](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ashevat/2010/03/12/how-to-implament-one-time-password-for-forgot-my-password-and-account-activation-processes) to generate the password. The add view only has three fields, first_name, last_name, and email (which is assigned to the username field in the Auth component).

Comment: Why wouldn't the first attempt work? And cake does _not_ remove the password. Why would it want to remove it when the Auth component only stores your hash.

Comment: What's failing when your first implementation fails? Is it saving a blank password, or a "wrong" password? The Auth component shouldn't be able to muck with `Model::save` call.

Comment: @JohnP - thanks for clearing that up. Probably mis-information.
@Daniel - The first method results in a blank password. Actually, they all result in a blank password.

Comment: @dbme the first method you tried is correct. Let's work with that. Is $random_pass populated properly? Also, check the $validate field of your UserModel. And a beforeSave if present.

Comment: @JohnP - Just for my sanity I disabled validation with save($user_data,false). It still adds a blank password. Then I verified that both the generated password and hashed password are populated (they are).

Comment: @dbme most curious. I work with cake for most of my projects, never come across this. Do a dump of `$this->data` in your beforeSave action in the model. See if it's empty there. And make sure to set debug to 2 and look at the SQL

Comment: @JohnP - I'm a total dumbass. I forgot that I put [this little gem](http://pastie.org/1675279) in the beforeSave action in an attempt to [validate the password](http://blog.boogly.net/2009/12/cakephp-login-form-with-password-confirmation-using-auth-component/) on the confirmation page. The password is getting saved now.

Comment: Another debugging approach: disable the Auth component, and empty/delete your User model. Can you save a password in plain-text? If so, start reenabling pieces of the chain until it breaks again.

Comment: @dbme yikes! also, you seem to be unsetting `data[User][password]` instead of `data[User][passwd]` , which is what you should be doing if you want to just have some confirm code.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I deserve the [double face palm](http://static.divbyzero.nl/facepalm/doublefacepalm.jpg). /me hides in shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JohnP answered this question in the comments. I had some junk in the beforeSave action. Removed and now it's working perfectly. Thanks again JohnP!

Answer (score 2):

first of all.. you can do

```
$random_pass = $this->Auth->password($this->generatePassword());
pr($random_pass);
```

to make sure there is actually data in that variable...

then you can save that data with...

```
$this->data['User']['password'] = $random_pass;
$this->User->save($this->data);
```

Also keep in mind that... during your testing you have if (!empty($this->data))
so make sure you are actually testing by entering some form of default data somewhere in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've got some validation rules defined in your User model that are not satisfied? You can try to check this by printing `$this->validationErrors` (or just check your User model to see if there are any rules).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cake PHP 2.3.3 and following code works for me

```
public function recover()
{
  if ($this->request->is('post') )
  {
    $this->loadModel('AclManagement.User');
    $passwords = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    $this->User->query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$passwords."' WHERE password_change = '".$this->request->data['User']['id']."' ");
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password Saved Sucessfully'), 'success');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
  } else {
    $this->set('resettoken', $_REQUEST['id']);
  }
}
```

Comment: **SQL injection alert!** Use parameterised queries, not string concatenation.